# No date input in MySQL when in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

Good day,

I am trying to insert an array of dates and options into MySQL.
This is done when a user selects dates from a dynamic list, chooses when they are available (=1) on a certain date, or unavailable. (=0)

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'dutch');
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");  
    $data = strtotime('+1 weeks');
    $datum = time();                

    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
    echo '<input name="UserID" type="hidden" value="' . wp_get_current_user()->ID . '">';
    echo '<ul id="datumselectie">';
    while ($datum <= $data) {
        echo '<li class="' .strftime('%A',$datum). '">';
        echo strftime('%A %e %B %Y',$datum);
        echo '<input type="radio" name="data[' .strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$datum). ']" value="1" />';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="data[' .strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$datum). ']" value="0" />';
        echo '</li>';
        $datum += 86400;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<input name="submit" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Opslaan" disabled/>'; 
    echo '</form>';
?>
```

The output is then inserted into MySQL using the following code:

```
$UserID = $_POST['UserID'];
foreach( $_POST['data'] as $datum2 => $beschikbaarheid) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Werkdagen (UserID, Datum, bevestigd, invuldatum, beschikbaarheid) VALUES ($UserID, $datum2, FALSE, NOW(), $beschikbaarheid)"); 
}
```

This works perfectly fine, however, the dates from the radio buttons gets inserted as `0000-00-00`, instead of e.g. `2014-06-23`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You'll need to use quotes inside some of your variables in `VALUES ($UserID, $datum2, FALSE, NOW(), $beschikbaarheid)` for example `VALUES ($UserID, '$datum2', FALSE, NOW(), '$beschikbaarheid')`

Comment: Try this: `var_dump($_POST['data']);` ...

Comment: Fred -ii-'s solution worked. I can't believe I overlooked something so simple! Thanks a bunch!